# Difference between RxJava API and the Java 9 Flow API

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, java-9

It seems on every iteration of Java for the last few major releases, there are consistently new ways to manage concurrent tasks.

In Java 9, we have the [Flow API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Flow.html) which resembles the [Flowable API](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?io/reactivex/Flowable.html) of RxJava but with Java 9 has a much simpler set of classes and interfaces.

**Java 9**

Has a `Flow.Publisher`, `Flow.Subscriber`, `Flow.Processor`, `Flow.Subscription`, and `SubmissionPublisher`, and that's about it.

**RxJava**

Has whole *packages* of [Flow API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Flow.html)-like classes, i.e. `io.reactivex.flowables`, `io.reactivex.subscribers`, `io.reactivex.processors`, `io.reactivex.observers`, and `io.reactivex.observables` which seem to do something similar.

What are the main differences between these two libraries? Why would someone use the Java 9 Flow library over the much more diverse RxJava library or vice versa?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> What are the main differences between these two libraries?

The Java 9 Flow API is not a standalone library but a component of the Java Standard Edition library and consists of 4 interfaces adopted from the [Reactive Streams](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm) specification established in early 2015. In theory, it's inclusion can enable in-JDK specific usages, such as the incubating HttpClient, maybe the planned Async Database Connection in parts, and of course `SubmissionPublisher`.

RxJava is Java library that uses the ReactiveX style API design to provide a rich set of operators over reactive (push) dataflows. Version 2, through `Flowable` and various `XxxProcessor`s, implements the Reactive Streams API which allows instances of `Flowable` to be consumed by other compatible libraries and in turn one can wrap any `Publisher` into a `Flowable` to consume those and compose the rich set of operators with them.

So the Reactive Streams API is the **minimal interface specification** and RxJava 2 is one **implementation** of it, plus RxJava declares a large set of additional methods to form a rich and fluent API of its own.

RxJava 1 inspired, among other sources, the Reactive Streams specification but couldn't capitalize on it (had to remain compatible). RxJava 2, being a full rewrite and a separate main version, could embrace and use the Reactive Streams specification (and even expand upon it internally, thanks to the [Rsc](https://github.com/reactor/reactive-streams-commons) project) and has been released almost a year before Java 9. In addition, it was decided both v1 and v2 keeps supporting Java 6 and thus a lot of Android runtimes. Therefore it couldn't capitalize directly on the Flow API provided now by Java 9 directly but only through a [bridge](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Jdk9Interop). Such bridge is required by and/or provided in other Reactive Streams-based libraries too.

RxJava 3 may target the Java 9 Flow API but this hasn't been decided yet and depending on what features the subsequent Java versions bring (i.e., value types), we may not have v3 within a year or so.

Till then, there is a prototype library called [Reactive4JavaFlow](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow#reactive4javaflow) which does implement the Flow API and offers a ReactiveX style rich fluent API over it.

> Why would someone use the Java 9 Flow library over the much more diverse RxJava library or vice versa?

The Flow API is an interoperation specification and not an end-user API. Normally, you wouldn't use it directly but to pass flows around to various implementations of it. When JEP 266 was discussed, the authors didn't find any existing library's API good enough to have something default with the Flow API (unlike the rich `java.util.Stream`). Therefore, it was decided that users will have to rely on 3rd party implementations for now.

You have to wait for existing reactive libraries to support the Flow API natively,  through their own bridge implementation or new libraries to be implemented.

Providing a rich set of operators over the Flow API is only reason a library would implement it. Datasource vendors (i.e., reactive database drivers, network libraries) can start implementing their own data accessors via the Flow API and rely on the rich libraries to wrap those and provide the transformation and coordination for them without forcing everybody to implement all sorts of these operators.

Consequently, a better question is, should you start using the Flow API-based interoperation now or stick to Reactive Streams?

If you need working and reliable solutions relatively soon, I suggest you stick with the Reactive Streams ecosystem for now. If you have plenty of time or you want to explore things, you could start using the Flow API.

Answer (score 51):

At the beginning, there was Rx, version one. It was a language agnostic specification of reactive APIs that has implementations for Java, JavaScript, .NET. Then they improved it and we saw [Rx 2](http://reactivex.io). It has implementations for different languages as well. At the time of Rx 2 Spring team was working on [Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) — their own set of reactive APIs.

And then they all thought: why not make a joint effort and create one API to rule them all. That was how [Reactive Commons](https://github.com/reactor/reactive-streams-commons) was set up. A joint research effort for building highly optimized reactive streams compliant operators. Current implementors include RxJava2 and Reactor.

At the same time JDK developers realized that reactive stuff is great and worth including in Java. As it is usual in Java world the de facto standard become de jure. Remeber Hibernate and JPA, Joda Time and Java 8 Date/Time API? So what JDK develpers did is extracting the very core of reactive APIs, the most basic part, and making it a standard. That is how `j.u.c.Flow` was born.

Technically, `j.u.c.Flow` is much more simpler, it consists only of [four simple interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html), while other libraries provide dozens of classes and hundreds of operators.

I hope, this answers the question "what is the difference between them".

Why would someone choose `j.u.c.Flow` over Rx? Well, because now it is a standard!

Currently JDK ships with only one implementation of `j.u.c.Flow`: [HTTP/2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?jdk.incubator.httpclient-summary.html). It is actually an incubating API. But in future we might expect support of it from Reactor, RxJava 2 as well as from other libraries, like reactive DB drivers or even FS IO.

Comment: You had conflated a few events. The Reactive Streams initiative was the gathering point somewhat after RxJava 0.x became stable enough. The Reactive Streams Commons came early 2016 with the aim you correctly stated.

Answer (score 10):

"What are the main differences between these two libraries?"

As you noted yourself, the Java 9 library is much more basic and basically serves as a general API for reactive streams instead of a full-fledged solution.

"Why would someone use the Java 9 Flow library over the much more diverse RxJava library or vice versa?"

Well, for the same reason people use basic library constructs over libraries - one less dependency to manage. Also, due to the fact that the Flow API in Java 9 is more general, it is less constrained by the specific implementation.

Answer (score 5):

### What are the main differences between these two libraries?

This mostly holds true as an informative comment(but too long to fit in), the ***[JEP 266: More Concurrency Updates](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/266)*** responsible for the introduction of the `Flow` API in Java9 states this in its description(emphasis mine) -

- > Interfaces supporting the *Reactive Streams publish-subscribe
  >   framework*, nested within the new class **Flow**.
- > `Publisher`s produce items
  >   consumed by one or more `Subscriber`s, each managed by a `Subscription`.
- > Communication relies on a simple form of flow control (method
  >   `Subscription.request`, for communicating back pressure) that can be
  >   used to avoid resource management problems that may otherwise occur in
  >   "push" based systems. A utility class `SubmissionPublisher` is provided
  >   that developers can use to create custom components.
- > ***These (very
  >   small) interfaces correspond to those defined with broad participation
  >   (from the Reactive Streams initiative) and support interoperability
  >   across a number of async systems running on JVMs.***
- > Nesting the interfaces within a class is a ***conservative policy allowing 
  >   their use across various short-term and long-term possibilities***. There 
  >   are no plans to provide network- or I/O-based `java.util.concurrent` 
  >   components for distributed messaging, *but it is possible that future JDK 
  >   releases will include such APIs in other packages*.

<sub>Why would someone use the Java 9 Flow library over the much more diverse RxJava library or vice versa?</sub>

Looking at a wider prospect this is completely opinion based on factors like the type of application a client is developing and its usages of the framework.